# Trying to automate git, commit only called "T"

Tags: c, git

I have been trying to make my workload for uploading my FRC java code to github as pain-free as possible. In this, I have made this program:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("Adding files to commit.\n");
    system("git add *");

    _TCHAR* commit = argv[1];
    printf("Committing changes\n");
    char* buffer = new char[300];
    sprintf(buffer, "git commit -m '%s' *", commit);
    system(buffer);

    printf("Status:\n");
    system("git status");

    printf("Uploading...\n");
    system("git push origin master");

    printf("Done!");

    return 0;
}
```

Problem is that when I pass the argument "Test", the commit is named "'T'". How can I fix this?

Comment: There are git hooks in the `.git/hooks` directory they can be executed before or after a commit, you can add the `push` there. It's not a good idea to write a c program which only invokes shell commands, that's what shell scripts are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you building your program as a Unicode program, so all your `TCHAR`-typed variables are Unicode.  When you pass `commit` to `sprintf()` there's no type checking done on the argument since it's part of the vararg parameters. And in a Unicode string, `"Test"` would have a byte with the value `'T'` followed by a byte with the value `0` - ending the string as far as `sprintf()` is concerned.

I suggest dumping the `TCHAR` types and just use `char` types for this simple program.  If you don't want to do that, then go whole hog and use `TCHAR`-based functions including `_tprintf()` instead of mixing `TCHAR` functions with plain old `char` functions.

Comment: Thank you, I changed all the _TCHAR* in the code to char*, and It worked.  By any chance, are you a part of FRC?

Comment: I don't think so - I have no idea what FRC is.